# How to show an object as tooltip using bootstrap syntax in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have an object like this
`var obj = {"test price type ty dynamic ": 10, test: 7, pricetype1u: 0, Price type 3: 0, Price type 2: 0}`

in an angular component html, using bootstrap i written like this

```
<button type="button" 
        icon="file-excel" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-placement="top"
        title="{{obj}}">

        <span class="k-icon k-i-info"></span>
</button>
```

tooltip is showing like (object) this:

```
{
  "test price type ty dynamic ": 10, 
   "test": 7, 
   "pricetype1u": 0, 
   "Price type 3": 0, 
   "Price type 2": 0  
}
```

my requirement is to show tooltip like this

```
  test price type ty dynamic : 10
  test : 7
  pricetype1u : 0
  Price type 3 : 0
  Price type 2 : 0
```

please help me how can i get this required format

Comment: Do you need this format for all object tooltips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this requirement for all your object tooltips, you should consider a pipe. Copy below implementation into a pipe should be work.

If you just need this format once, you can just write a simple function to handle it:

```
function convertObjTooltip(obj: any) {
    const results = [];
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((sum, key) => {
        sum.push(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
        return sum;
    }, results);
    return results.join('\n');
}
```

I didn't remove the first change line, you can handle it by yourself.

Calling it in your template:

```
<button type="button" 
    icon="file-excel" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-placement="top"
    title="{{convertObjTooltip(obj)}}">
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much huan ...

i written a console it always triggering in background , it is good practice

Comment: Yes, Actually binding property to function call is not a good idea, you can avoid this by simple assign the calculated value to variable in component, and use that value in template. This should avoid the performance issue.

Comment: as you asked me to do i created angular pipe so it will be called once only and working fine.... Thank You huan.